# How to position text on image using position as absolute while container width being in percent

Tags: html, css

I have been doing some practice in CSS and HTML and while creating a layout for page I faced this problem here is the first code.
note: below codes are just example of problem which I faced while creating layout

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
        *
        {margin:0px;padding:0px;box-sizing:border-box;}
        #container
        {
            width:800px;
            position:relative;
            background-color:darkgray;
        }

        #temp
        {
            position: relative;
        }
        #content
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:100px;
            right:120px;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:1px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="temp">
            <img src="psp.jpg" alt="no imgage">
        <div id="content">
        <h1>
          Goku Vs Vegeta 
             <form>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Start fighting" name="img">
             </form>   
             </h1>    
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works perfectly for me the text remain's exactly on the image whether we increase or decrease the zoom of browser the text does not changes it position.

The problem arrives when I change the container width from pixel to percentage here is the second code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
        *
        {margin:0px;padding:0px;box-sizing:border-box;}
        #container
        {
            width:100%;
            position:relative;
            background-color:darkgray;
        }

        #temp
        {
            position: relative;
        }
        #content
        {
            position:absolute;
            top:100px;
            right:120px;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            border:1px solid yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="temp">
            <img src="psp.jpg" alt="no imgage">
        <div id="content">
        <h1>
          Goku Vs Vegeta 
             <form>
                 <input type="text" placeholder="Start fighting" name="img">
             </form>   
             </h1>    
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with the second code is if we increase or decrease the zoom of browser the position of text will change and it will not be relative to image rather it will be to view port of browser or to the container but not to the image. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/30d2nqeL/

Comment: What is the size of the psp.jpg img?

Comment: @Toby size is 263 KB & width:1336 height:768

Comment: And what is it exactly you're looking to achieve? I can't see the image, so I'm not sure if there's something in the image that makes it obvious where the box should go. Can you link to the image online? Or explain further..

Comment: @Toby i have uploaded js fiddle file check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
        * {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        #container {
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          background-color: darkgray;
        }
        
        #temp {
position: relative;
          background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1336/768');
          background-size: cover;
          height: 400px;
          padding: 0 10vh;
        }
        
        #content {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -100px;
right: 0;
margin-right: 10%;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          border: 1px solid yellow;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        }
        
        #content h1 {
          text-align: center;
margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
          color: #000;
        }
#content form {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="temp">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Goku Vs Vegeta</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Start fighting" name="img">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. form in h1 - bad practice.
2. use css background-image.
3. check flexbox.

```css
* {
          margin: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        #container {
          width: 100%;
          position: relative;
          background-color: darkgray;
        }
        
        #temp {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          flex-direction: row-reverse;
          background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1336/768');
          background-size: cover;
          height: 768px;
          padding: 0 10vh;
        }
        
        #content {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
          width: 200px;
          height: 200px;
          border: 1px solid yellow;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
        }
        
        #content h1 {
          text-align: center;
          margin: -.4em 0 1em 0;
          color: #000;

        }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="temp">
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Goku Vs Vegeta</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Start fighting" name="img">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool this works but is there any way to work without flex box and only using position property ?

Comment: Ya. see my second answer.